# How to loop animation with delay?

Tags: jquery

I have images that change every 5000ms and I wanted to put subtitles on them. I have this:

```
    function showEl1(){
        $('#wrap').animate({ 
                left: '-450',
            }, 500, function() { 
                $('#wrap').html($('#el1').html()); 
            }).animate({ left: '70',}, 500);
        setTimeout(showEl2, 5000);
    }

    function showEl2(){
        $('#wrap').animate({ 
                left: '-450',
            }, 500, function() { 
                $('#wrap').html($('#el2').html()); 
            }).animate({ left: '70',}, 500);
        setTimeout(showEl3, 5000);
    }

    function showEl3(){
        $('#wrap').animate({ 
                left: '-450',
            }, 500, function() { 
                $('#wrap').html($('#el3').html()); 
            }).animate({ left: '70',}, 500);
        setTimeout(showEl1, 5000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        showEl1();
    }
```

And it works but... I want to hide subtitles a little earlier, wait a moment and then show the next. How to do it?

Comment: You have a few errors there. Many unexpected `,` and a missing `);`

Comment: @elclanrs: Trailing `,` are valid.

Comment: They might cause problems with some browsers. Why would you use them like that anyway? It's not very readable. If you use something like jslint it'll tell you, nop! that's not the right way to do it...

Comment: @elclanrs I'm pretty sure he didn't ask the question for you to tell him you don't like the way his code looks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping each setTimeout in another setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { setTimeout(showElq, 5000); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, it guided me to delay() function